# Render after the completion of componentdidmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

i am trying to update fileList value to the Upload component. However, the `handleOne` function keeps displaying `[]`. And from the console, i can see that the `handleOne` function executes before the `getFirebaseURL` function. Is there a way that i can wait until `componentDidMount` completes all the `setState` method, and then render the page? I have tried to use `componentWillMount()` and `shouldUpdate()`, Both of them does not work. Can anyone help me? 
Thank you so much!

```
handleOne = () => {
  console.log(this.state.data)
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('/user/product')
    .then(res=>{
      if(res.data.code==0) {
        this.setState({data:res.data.data}, function(){
          for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
             // this getURL function also contains setState
             this.getFirebaseURL(this.state.data[i].productName) 
          }
        })
      }
    })
}


render(){
  <Upload fileList= {this.handleOne()}>
  </Upload>
}
```

**Updated**

```
 getFirebaseURL = product => {
   // Get all the images from the firebase
    var storage = firebase.storage();
    var that = this;
    var i = 0;
    const storageRef =  storage.ref(`image/${product}`)

    // Get all the URL
    storageRef.listAll().then(function(result) {
      result.items.forEach(function(imageRef) {
        imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {  

              i = i + 1;
              let object = {}
              object['uid'] = i.toString();
              object['name'] = product;
              object['url'] = url;

              let list = []
              list.push(object)
              // temp3 is an array        
              that.state.temp3.push(list)
            }).catch(function(error) {});        
         })
       })          
    }
```

Comment: You can use conditional rendering. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58832859/1452861](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58832859/1452861)

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional rendering like below:

```
render(){
  {this.state.data && <Upload fileList= {this.handleOne()}> }
  </Upload>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extract te get function from the componentDidMount function. I'd call it getUser().

```
  getUser = () => {
    return axios.get("/user").then(res => {
      if (res.data.code == 0) {
        this.setState({ data: res.data.data }, function() {
          // this getURL function also contains setState
          this.state.data.map(i => this.getFirebaseURL(i));
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

This function returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which you need to await in componentDidMount().

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getUser()
  }
```

Comment: Hi Jurrian. Thanks for your answer, but it does not work.

Comment: Could you share the getFirebaseURL function?

Comment: & what type of object does the '/user' endpoint provide? I can't get my head around this condition: `res.data.code == 0`, could you explain this?

Comment: the backend will provide an array.  `res.data.code == 0` means that get data successfully.